# how to load intellij settings on startup

Tags: intellij-idea, eclipse-plugin

In eclipse we have to extend AbstractPreferenceInitializer, and define the below lines in plugin xml, to load preference details on eclipse startup.

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences">
  <initializer
        class="org.example.preferences.PreferenceInitializer"> 
  </initializer>
</extension>
```

How do we do the same thing in intellij?

Comment: What does the preference details provide you?

Comment: it is just some string values

Answer (score 0):

[Persisting State of Components](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/persisting_state_of_components.html?search=state)

Comment: yes I m doing something similar to store the values in preference (settings).   But I want to load my preferences/settings automatically when i open my preference page /settings page.

Comment: Your settings is loaded automatically, you should keep it in your PersistentStateComponent as a field, so just pass it to the settings page.